Download PDF using react-pdf
I am using react-pdf for rendering Pdf file and it's working perfectly fine.
Below is the code for same:
    <Document
            inputRef={documentRef}
            file={pdfUrl}
            error={() => {}}
            onLoadSuccess={(params) => {
              console.log('paramsparams => ', params);
            }}
          >
            <Page
              renderTextLayer={true}
              renderAnnotationLayer={true}
              customTextRenderer={false}
              pageNumber={1}
              renderForms={true}
            />
          </Document>
<button onCLick={()=>// access updated pdf buffer }>Save</button>

This is rendering text layer along with form fields. As pdf is having form fields I want my user to fill in it and I should be able to store copy of filled pdf.
currently user are able to fill in details but how can I get access to updated pdf buffer object which should contains pdf with filled form so that I can create and store pdf on server?

To work with a PDF that has form fields in your React app, you can use react-pdf for displaying the PDF and a library like pdf-lib to modify and generate the filled PDF. react-pdf is mainly for viewing PDFs, but it doesn't allow you to edit or extract the filled form data. By combining it with pdf-lib, you can fill out the form fields and get the updated PDF.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-lib (link to pdf-lib)
Here’s a simple guide to help you get the updated PDF buffer:
Steps:

Render the PDF: Use react-pdf to display the PDF.
Fill the form: Use a library like pdf-lib to modify the form fields in the PDF.
Generate the updated PDF: Save the filled PDF and send it to the server for storage.

